# How to make interactive labels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a small application what will be used as a Template Manager. I would like to ask that how to do that in one user form it will show the data in the following way. Will check .xml file and what is inside   tags will be shown one under the other. So lets say I have 5 items with this tag, so all 5 will be listed one under another.

I have something like this, but this is opening a new new MessageBox and showing them one by one.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string Username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
  var str = Username;
  var result = str.Length <= 4 ? "" : str.Substring(4);
  string path = $"C:\\Users\\{result}\\Documents

  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load(path);
  XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(path);
  while (xtr.Read())
  {
    if (xtr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xtr.Name == "name")
    {
      string string_title = xtr.ReadElementString();
      // Console.WriteLine("Name = "+ s1);
      MessageBox.Show("Title: " + Environment.NewLine + string_title);
    }
  }
```

I have a second from called Form2 for now, I can refer in this way as an example new Form2().Show(); but how do I make the lables on the form change according to what is in the xml file between specific tags?

Comment: Unrelated: `string path = $"C:\\Users\\{result}\\Documents` is missing a closing `";`

Comment: Do I get that right: You want to show a list of the contents of the "name" nodes? Then why use labels? Use a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.7.2). It also gives you scrolling if the list exceeds the height of the control / Window for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
  string string_title;

  while (xtr.Read())
  {
    if (xtr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xtr.Name == "name")
    {
      string_title += xtr.ReadElementString() + Environment.NewLine;
      // Console.WriteLine("Name = "+ s1);
    }
  }

  MessageBox.Show("Title: " + string_title);
```

Guessing if you are calling form 2 from form 1 on the button click. You can do as below.

Inside button click.

```
var form2 = new Form2(string_title);
form2.show();
```

Inside form 2.

```
string dataFromForm1;
public Form2(string data) {
 dataFromForm1 = data;
}
```

Inside form 2 show method.

```
public void show(){
   MessageBox.Show("Title: " + dataFromForm1);
}
```